# How to debug the method I have set up using PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute assembly attribute while running on IIS 7.5?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis-7

I have declared the `PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute` on the assembly level like this:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyApp.Global), "InitializeApplication")]
```

See [this explanation](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx) for more details on that.

Here's the declaration of `InitializeApplication`:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    public static void InitializeApplication()
    {
        // Initialization code goes here...
    }
}
```

I am running my application on a local IIS 7.5 instance and I want to debug my `InitializeApplication` method. I have set a break point on it but it doesn't get hit.

I figure that the code is executed when the Application Pool starts, which to my knowledge is before the point when I hit F5 in Visual Studio.

I have tried to attach the debugger to any IIS related process I could find but to no avail.

I also realize that I can debug using Cassini but I need to fix an IIS related issue here.

So, the question is: how can I debug the `PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute` designated method?

Comment: Did you tried to attach to local IIS or remote?

Comment: I attached locally. I've updated the question, thanks for helping me make the question more specific.

Comment: Do you use IIS Express or regular IIS 7? Try both for more understanding of the problem and experience

Comment: At first sight, attaching to IIS process is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that using IIS 7.5 Express, the initialization method is hit by the debugger when running after a rebuild. If you post your reply as an answer, I'll accept it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use IIS Express locally, probably it will be easier to attach debugger to it's process.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` in your initialization code. When the debugger is attached this breakpoint will always hit.

If you want to attach to a process running in IIS, use "Attach to process" (Ctrl + Alt + p), and look for w3wp.exe, you should be able to identify the correct process by the username (apppool user) and type (managed). If the process is not listed, make sure you checked "Show processes from all users". Of course the process needs to be running, so you might need to fire a request first.

A good approach would be to *Publish* your project to a local folder, which you use as a basepath in IIS, as opposed to pointing IIS directly at your codebase. If you do this, the w3wp process ussualy doesn't need to restart after a republish, so you can easily attach the debugger in subsequent debugging attempts.